# IOS : Distribution (release) configuration bugs and crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, release, distribution

I've created an app to solve sudoku grids...but
here is my problem : my app has some bug and even crashes with my Distribution Configuration for compiling (equivalent to Release Configuration).

Here is the code where it bugs :

```
- (int*)completeNb:(int[9][9])aMatrix {
    int n, nb;
    int cell[2];
    int *pcell;
    BOOL found = FALSE;
    BOOL pos = FALSE;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
        n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if (aMatrix[i][j] == k)
                    n++;
            }
        }
        if (n == 8) {
            found = TRUE;
            nb = k;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < 9; m++) {
                if ([self isPossibleValue:aMatrix value:nb line:l column:m]) {
                    cell[0] = l;
                    cell[1] = m;
                    pos = TRUE;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (pos)
                break;
        }
        pcell = cell;
    }
    else {
        pcell = nil;
    }
    return pcell;
}
```

I have a special sudoku grid where I should find {6,6} as the right position for number 6 (6 should at *i=6* and *j=6* in the grid). It works perfectly in Debug Configuration, but with Distrib Conf, it seems like I have problem with the *l* and *m* vars -> the loop breaks well at *l=6* and *m=6* (hence, *isPossibleValue* function seems to work well), but then my *cell* variable is equal to {1;0}, instead of {6;6} !

I am using this kind of process (returning a *cell[2]*) with many other functions, and I don't have any problem with the Distrib Conf.

My second problem, - and this one is provoking the app to crash - is with the following code (again, perfectly working with debug configuration).

```
- (void)solver:(int[9][9])aMatrix {
    if (!Termine) {
        int *emptyCell = [self firstEmptyCell:aMatrix];
        if (emptyCell != nil) {
            int i = emptyCell[0];
            int j = emptyCell[1];
            for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
                if ([self isPossibleValue:aMatrix value:k line:i column:j]) {
                    aMatrix[i][j] = k;
                    [self solver:aMatrix];
                    aMatrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!Termine) {
                Termine = TRUE;
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                        res[i][j] = aMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note : one solution, - I am not sure that's the best one - is to change optimization level from "fastest, smallest" to "none".

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case the problem is in `int cell[2];`. It has a local scope, and after you return from the function the memory zone pointed by this array very likely will be reallocated for other needs. A quick solution is to add `static` specifier:

```
static int cell[2];
```

For the second snippet, make sure that `emptyCell` each time assigns to `i` and `j` values which doesn't exceed `aMatrix` bounds [0..8][0..8].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What should I do to solve the first problem with the int cell[2] ? (it always return {1,0}) Should I use a global var ?  

For the *emptyCell* function, it shouldnt return i,j out of aMatrix bounds, but i'm using the same process for returning the coordinates (with a int cell[2]...)

Comment: Ah, you answered to by question by editing your post. I'm trying with the "static" word

Comment: For the first case the simplest way is to add 'static' specifier for 'cell' declaration. But if you want to create multiple instance you will need to copy each 'array' element 'one-by-one'.  [Here](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html) is the great doc about returning arrays.

Comment: It works with the static specified, thanks a lot ! What do you mean with the creation of multiple instance ? In one same function ?

Comment: For example if you want to use this function to populate 2 or more arrays as follow: `int *a = [obj completeNb:aMatrix1];` and `int *b = [obj completeNb:aMatrix2];` In this case `a` and `b` will point to the same memory zone and therefore will contain the same values.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean ! Thanks again